# Unable to click the option from Hover menu in Naukri website

Tags: java, selenium

When trying to click on Manage Profile option from My Naukri hover menu, unable to locate the element and getting`org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <a href="https://my.naukri.com/ManageProfiles/view"> could not be scrolled into view` exception

```
for(String ManageProfileWindow : naukriProfileCreation.getWindowHandles())
            {
                naukriProfileCreation.switchTo().window(ManageProfileWindow);
            }


Actions hovermenu = new Actions(naukriProfileCreation);
Thread.sleep(4000);
WebElement ManageProfile = naukriProfileCreation.findElement(By.linkText("Manage Profiles"));
Thread.sleep(4000);
((JavascriptExecutor)naukriProfileCreation).executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + ManageProfile.getLocation().x + "," + ManageProfile.getLocation().y + ")");
            naukriProfileCreation.findElement(By.cssSelector(".rghtSec > li:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
ManageProfile.click();
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="https://my.naukri.com/ManageProfiles/view" title="Manage Profiles">Manage Profiles</a></li><li><a href="https://resume.naukri.com/subscription" title="My Fastforward Services">My Fastforward Services</a></li><li><a href="https://login.naukri.com/nLogin/Logout.php" title="Logout">Logout</a></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Could you add the original HTML as your link is redirecting me to login Naukri website

Comment: @Vinoth Can you clean up your code trials (remove commented code) so volunteers can identify your exact steps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mouse over on the parent menu of `Manage Profile` to make submeun display out before you can operate on any submenu.

You can't directly to operate it when it's not visible from UI.

```
WebElement parentMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='My Naukri']"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(parentMenu).perform();

WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Manage Profiles']"));

subMenu.click();
```

Comment: tried above code and getting target out of bound exception.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (683, 1084.5499877929688) is out of bounds of viewport width (1366) and height (664)